# How can I use Excel to monitor my payable?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

Here's what I wanted to happen, I have five columns

```
Supplier    Amount    Payment   Supplier1   Supplier2
```

When I have a receipt of my payable, I'll encode the name of supplier and it's amount. When I did that, I want the amount of that receipt to appear on the column of that supplier. Example: I encoded Supplier1 and 12,000; I want 12,000 to appear under the Supplier1 column.

And when I do a payment, same with the scenario above but the amount that will appear on the column of that supplier is in negative format so I can determine the balance of my payable on that supplier. Example: Supplier1 10,000; I want (10,000) to appear under Supplier1 column.

Can I do this format on Excel? If yes, how?

Comment: A pivot table would be a better way of summarizing your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sounds like a job for [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-AU/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)!

<sup>(part of my "Sounds Like a Job For Pivot Table!" series)</sup>

---

With your data, highlight it, go to *insert - pivot table*

[click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkNem.png)
[image]

Then in *pivot table tools* go to *options - formulas - calculated field*

[click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsTTd.png)

[image]

Name it whatever you want, but set it up so it's `invoice - payment`

Now you can construct the pivot table. I'd go with **Supplier** as row label and then drag **invoice** and **payment** into the values box, which will create a sum of values in column labels. Now drag your calculated field down to the values box. Bam! You got yourself a stew going!

[click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WepFe.png)
[image]